# SelectIndex_changed not worling in Asp.net for selecting values

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am new on .net development now i am facing the problem but i do not know what the solution for this
i am creating the dropdown list and bind it with data but when i select the any data from list it does not changes the textbox with the related value but when i click on button it goes inside the code means goes on debuging from where i mark the debug cursor
here is my code behind

```
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedCardCode = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

                 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=testing;Initial Catalog=testdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abcd;Password=asdfg");
            using (connection)
            {
                SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName,T3.CntctCode,T3.Name  FROM OCRD T1 inner join OCPR T3 on T1.CardCode=T3.CardCode where T3.CardCode=@CardCode ", connection);
                connection.Open();
                theCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardCode", selectedCardCode);
                theCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                SqlDataReader theReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (theReader.Read())
                {
                    this.TextBox1.Text = theReader["CardCode"].ToString();
                    this.TextBox2.Text = theReader["CardName"].ToString();
                    this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value = selectedCardCode;

                        }
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
```

and here is my method cardcode

```
 protected void LoadOptionsCardCodeTable()
        {
            DataTable CardCode = new DataTable();
            string id, name, newName;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=abc;Initial Catalog=TestDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=asdf;Password=asdfgh");
            using (connection)
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName from ocrd T1 ", connection);
                adapter.Fill(CardCode);

                if (CardCode.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < CardCode.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        id = CardCode.Rows[i]["CardCode"].ToString();
                        name = CardCode.Rows[i]["CardName"].ToString();
                        newName = name + " ---- " + id;

                        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(newName, id));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

here is my design code

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            ondatabinding="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
```

Kindly help your help will be higly appreciatable

Comment: you are missing to set AutoPostBack property.. set it to true in markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack` property to true for your dropdownlist.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
      ondatabinding="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
       onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

By default, asp.net server controls like dropdownlist, textbox have their respective events as *cached* which means it registers the event but does not fire untill an actual *postback* happens. In you case when you are clicking the button a postback is happening and the cached event of your dropdwonlist is also getting executed.

To force postback from your dropdown you will have to set the *PostBack* property to **true**.

Comment: can you plz tell the other problem what i facing i drag the button in my aspx file and when i double click on that button it shows the error not run fine

Comment: @Ismail - What error? delete the button and try to do it afresh again.

Comment: I did but not working but when i create new project and do same it works fine

Comment: @Ismail - Clean your solution, rebuild it. It's sometimes the issue with auto generated designer file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `AutoPostBack="true"` in order to trigger the event:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            ondatabinding="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Notes:

A postback is initiated by the browser, and reloads the whole page, according to an event.if any changes(here `onselectedindexchanged`) we made in the control result in a postback then that are called AutoPostBack.All controls except, `Buttons`, `Hyperlinks` and `LinkButtons` have a default AutoPostBack property of false, we have an option to make them true if needed.

Comment: Thanks Alot for quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"` Otherwise `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't fire.

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            ondatabinding="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
         </asp:DropDownList>
```